# When send mail with base64 image in gmail It's not displaying

Tags: google-api, gmail

```
const html = "<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="e-rte-image e-imginline" alt="icon.png" width="auto" height="auto" style="min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px;"> </p>"
```

When mail is sent to the server its removing the src from image tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your html code is incorrect as you are using double quotes inside the string for  src and for other attributes as well which is a syntex error. Please rewrite this like this,

```
const html = '<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="e-rte-image e-imginline" alt="icon.png" width="auto" height="auto" style="min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px;"> </p>'
```